# nVIDIA support on xubuntu

Tags: nvidia

I have been using xubuntu on my portege m200 since version 11.10
with support for the internal nVIDIA GeForce graphics card
without any porblems.

But after the last major update there is no more hardware support for the nVIDIA card.
The GUI tool for proprietary drivers states that there ist some driver, but it is not active.

The question is: what is the correct package to get the card running?
And why did you remove the support for this card from version to version!?

Comment: The nvidia guys might have not updated the driver. Update and support for closed source software is maintained by the party not ubuntu. However what is your card model no ? you can get it by running `lspci | grep VGA`.

Comment: Just Remove and reinstall driver.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Synaptic package manager (can be found in the Software Center). Than look for ''nvidia''. There are different drivers available, my system works on `nvidia-current-updates`. (Xubuntu 12.10).